# Tick method in a PoliceOfficer class

Tags: python

My question deals with creating a tick procedure the original tick procedure where it makes a class called PoliceOfficer arrest everyone who is naked around him.

```
def tick(self):
# next time step for all objects that tick               
  for t in self.__things:          
  obj = self.get_thing(t)            
  if has_method(obj, "tick"):                
    obj.tick()
```

This the original tick method.

This is my `PoliceOfficer` class and the method known as `arrest`. The arrest method arrests someone based upon them not having any clothes on when in the area of the PoliceOfficer, and when there isn't anyone to arrest he just says something else.

```
class PoliceOfficer (Person):    
    def __init__(self, name, jail): 
        Person.__init__(self, name)
        self.set_restlessness(0.5)
        self.__jail = jail
    def arrest (self, Person):
      if self.location.name is Person.location.name:
          self.say (Person.name + "You're under arrest!")
          self.say ("You have the right to shut up and lay on the ground with your hands behind your back")
          Person.name(Place("jail")
      else:                
         return self.say (Person.name + "Ain't got nothing to do damnit") 
    def tick (self):
      if isinstance(t, Student):
      if Student.is_dressed = False:
          arrest.student       
      else:
        (Person)tick(): self.say("Shoot no one to arrest off to the 7 eleven")
```

Would this be partially correct on making my own tick method for PoliceOfficer? 
If not what else would I need to do or change to make it like the tick method described, except for making the PoliceOfficer arrest any student that isn't dressed?

Comment: `self.location.name is Person.location.name` tests for equal objects, not just equality. While equal strings are the same objects (since strings are immutable and everything else would be a waste of space), you should never assume this and use `==` instead.

Comment: `is` is not `==` (And no, @ThiefMaster, equal strings are not necessarily internet, that only happens for string literals). Double leading underscores are asking for trouble, name mangling will bite you if you ever want to refer to that attribute outside of the class (e.g. in subclasses!). Variable names (this includes parameter names) should be lower case with underscores.

Comment: You also need to post your code with the proper indentation as it's part of the Python syntax. Your first code block is invalid due to its missing indentation for example.

Comment: Also, using setter functions is not really necessary in python - you can use properties to achieve getter/setter-style behaviour without the hassle of calling getSomething and setSomething methods.

Comment: @delnan: I think in CPython they are. At least `'a' + 'b' is 'ab'` and `'ab'[:] is 'ab'`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Perhaps some peephole optimization. It's definitely an exception. Try defining `x` and `y` as e.g. `','.join(str(x) for x in range(100))` and check `x is y`.

Comment: A more specific title will help your question attract more attention.

Answer (score 3):

Uhm,... you want to test is an object is of a certain class? Python has a built-in function for that: `isinstance()`. Quick example:

```
>>> isinstance(1, int)
True
>>> isinstance("Hello World!", int)
False
>>> isinstance("Hello World!", str)
True
```

Check the documentation for more information.
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance

As per delnan's "suggestion", a little piece of advice: instead of checking for the class behind the Person you receive, it's cleaner to have `Person` implement a `canBeArrested()` method that subclasses can override, for which `Student` can return false.

```
class Person(object):
    (...)
    def canBeArrested(self):
        return True

class Diplomat(Person):
    (...)
    def canBeArrested(self):
        # Overrides Person's default behaviour
        return False
```

Comment: This is **not** a good idea. In fact, it's a very poor one. Use polymorphism (and ducktyping).

Comment: @delnan a little categoric, aren't we? Of course, in a duck-typed environment, you (almost) always avoid class checking, and even less so in production code. Keywords: almost, production code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

```
obj.__class__.__name__ == "Student"
```

or

```
isinstance(obj, Student)
```

I recommend the second way, but sometimes you really need the name of the class, for which `obj.__class__.__name__` is the way to go.

Comment: I can just repeat my comment to Santiago: This is **not** a good idea. In fact, it's a very poor one. Use polymorphism (and ducktyping). And the first one is even worse, as it doesn't account for polymorphism and misuses *debugging* information.

Comment: Better yet avoid OOP altogether and you won't have these problems

Comment: @delan Hmm so since my class isn't really a integer ducktyping would work really well for it so its simpler to use. Thanks I've looked it up I never even heard about it till now so I'll try to make some code with it and post it up and its right let me know.